# How can I use several windows by Ribbon

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon, mdi

I want to make a Desktop app for getting information and editing them. I choose Ribbon because I like it.

Each `RibbonTab`, has some information. I want the page under ribbon change to other window as I clicked a button in RibbonButton. Here is the code:

```
<DockPanel>                
    <RibbonTab Name="RealPersons_Rb" Header="Persons">
       <RibbonGroup Header="Persons">
           <RibbonButton Name="Btn1" Label="New Person"/>
       </RibbonGroup>
       <RibbonGroup Header="Edit">
           <RibbonButton Name="Btn2" Label="Edit information"/>                         
       </RibbonGroup>                     
   <RibbonTab Name="Car_Rb" Header="Cars"/>
  </Ribbon>
</DockPanel>
```

For each new `Person` I Have a Form that has been designed in a page. How Can I Insert that page into `DockPanel` below the Ribbon and change it?

Comment: If there is a better way to do this plz say.

Comment: Better: insert page within dockpanel

Comment: In Windowsform we can use MDI but in wpf?